# Scrapy problem with international text

Tags: python, scrapy

I did scraping text from webpage using scrapy. In spider, I have code like:

```
title = hxs.select("//h1/text()").extract() #1
final_text = title[0].encode('utf-8')   #2
```

Here problem is 
line #1 gives [u'Puerto Ban\xfas']
line #2 gives Puerto Ban\xc3\xbas

But original text was **Puerto Banús**. How can I get this original saved and displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> print u'Puerto Ban\xfas'
Puerto Banús
>>> print 'Puerto Ban\xc3\xbas'
Puerto Banús
```

I don't see a problem here.