# Scrapy retrieves text encoding incorrectly, hebrew as \u0d5 etc

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, scrapy

First time working with this stuff.
Checked out all other SOF questions about internalization / text encoding.

I'm doing the Scrapy tutorial, when I got stuck at this part: [Extracting Data](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-the-data),
When I extract the data, the text instead of hebrew displayed as a series of \uXXXX.

it's possible for you to check it out by scraping [this page](http://israblog.nana10.co.il/blogread.asp?blog=167524&blogcode=13348970) for example;

```
scrapy shell http://israblog.nana10.co.il/blogread.asp?blog=167524&blogcode=13348970
hxs.select('//h2[@class="title"]/text()').extract()[0]
```

this will retrieve

`u'\u05de\u05d9 \u05d0\u05e0\u05e1 \u05e4\u05d5\u05d8\u05e0\u05e6\u05d9\u05d0\u05dc\u05d9?'`

(unrelated:) if you try to print it in the console, you get:
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: cha
racter maps to <undefined>`

Tried setting the encoding through the settings, tried converting manually, basically I feel like I tried everything.

(I've gone already about 5 pomodoros trying to fix this!)

what can I do to get the hebrew text that should be there: "`מי אנס פוטנציאלי?`"

(Disclaimer: I just went into the first blog and post I noticed on http://Israblog.co.il, I'm in no way related to the blog or blog owner, I just used it as an example)

Comment: What's really odd, that using `scrapy view <url>` shows me hebrew, using `scrapy fetch <url>` shows me jibberish.

Comment: some more progress, i use this line `filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)` inside my parse method in the spider to generate a file containing the URLs HTML, and in Notepad++ when I open it; it's jibberish, but if I change in Encoding->character sets->Hebrew->windows-1255, I see the hebrew perfectly. How I can translate this behaviour to Scrapy?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7185755/1344461

Answer (score 2):

> what can I do to get the hebrew text that should be there: "מי אנס
>   פוטנציאלי?"

`test.py`:

```
# coding: utf-8

a = u'\u05de\u05d9 \u05d0\u05e0\u05e1 \u05e4\u05d5\u05d8\u05e0\u05e6\u05d9\u05d0\u05dc\u05d9?'
b = 'מי אנס פוטנציאלי?'

print a
print b
```

Result:

```
vic@wic:~/projects/snippets$ python test.py 
מי אנס פוטנציאלי?
מי אנס פוטנציאלי?
vic@wic:~/projects/snippets$
```

As you see they are the same. It's just different representation of the same unicode string. So don't worry that it's not scraped correctly.

If you want to save it to a file:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
>>> a = u'\u05de\u05d9 \u05d0\u05e0\u05e1 \u05e4\u05d5\u05d8\u05e0\u05e6\u05d9\u05d0\u05dc\u05d9'
>>> a
u'\u05de\u05d9 \u05d0\u05e0\u05e1 \u05e4\u05d5\u05d8\u05e0\u05e6\u05d9\u05d0\u05dc\u05d9'
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'w')
>>> f.write(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> f.write(a.encode('utf-8'))
>>> f.close()
```

Comment: But it's being written the same to the file. and since it's "unicode" and not string, I can't perform methods on it, such as replace, so what your saying isn't helpful to me.

Comment: @Saga: Incorrect. These methods still work as explained here: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @Saga, i think i don't understand your problem. can you make a test case to show your problem (to demonstrate your problem: "But it's being written the same to the file. and since it's "unicode" and not string, I can't perform methods on it, such as replace")?

Comment: My error came from misunderstanding how unicode works, and my own erroneous presuppositions (of which I wasn't even aware! until I started asking myself "Hey.. why do you think it works that way?").

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see what do you get when storing that information you get from the page somewhere in json, xml....

I had those problems with some signs on few sites and in most cases if you don't do anything with the retrieved data it gets stored properly, but if you try to print them out in console you won't get proper result, or it will give error if you don't use repr

```
print repr(data)
```

I hope this helps, cause I know the frustration of encoding problems.

Comment: when I use the feed exports to export to a JSON file, it is exactly the same.